# Javascript, PHP, AJAX: how to echo arrays and append them into a html division

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am a beginner and I am trying to echo arrays and append them into a html division i created. The AJAX call I made was successful but the response was not appearing inside the division i assigned it to. Upon further inspection, I found out that the response I have received has an array length over 600 ( I am expecting 10 records). So there must be something wrong with my echo PHP file or the receiving end of the HTML file but just cannot figure out what that is.

Here are my codes:

listdiscount.php

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "bencoolen");

$userid = $_GET['userid'];

$result = $conn->query("select userid, codename from discountcode where userid ='" . $userid . "' ");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     printf("Userid: %s '' Codename: %s", $row["userid"], $row["codename"]);
 }

 $conn->close(); 
?>
```

index.html ( with js codes )

```
<html>
<script>
    function mydiscount(){
                          var userid = "jimmy"; 
                            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            var url = serverURL() + "/listdiscount.php";
                            url += "?userid=" + userid; 
                            alert(url);
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                    alert("readystate=4 and status =200");
                                    mydiscountresult(xmlhttp.responseText);
                                }
                                }
                                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                                xmlhttp.send();
                        }

                        function mydiscountresult(response) {
                            var arr = response;
                            alert(arr);         //alerted
                            alert(arr.length);  //alerted 600+ arrays
                            alert("mydiscountresult working"); //alerted
                            var i;
                            $("#discountcontent").empty();
                            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            $("#discountcontent").append("<b>" + arr[i].userid + "</b>"+ arr[i].codename + "<hr>");
                            }
                        }

                        mydiscount();
</script>

                    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="discount">
                    LIST OF DISCOUNT CODE:<br>
                    <div id="discountcontent" class="ui-grid-solo">
                    </div>
                    </div>
</html>
```

Here is what my response look like when alerted:

addition note: my php files are in different folder so serverurl() is declared and used here.

Comment: It seems that the response is missing ?

Comment: try to console/alert the value of arr[i].userid etc and also check the console for any error reported.

Comment: Yeap sure i'll alert the array userid in a couple minutes ! also ill add in the response too, i forgot!!

Comment: BTW: You are using jQuery. So you **can** use a simple ajax call 
`$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

the get request returns a json array so you need to convet it in to normal array using json parse. you may please change the line of code as

```
   mydiscountresult(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Function `xmlhttp.responseText` retun a *String*, right?

You gave this *string* into function `mydiscountresult` and copy it into variable `var`. It is still a *string*, isn't it?

So the alerts work fine and do there jobs on the *string* (length 600 and so on)

Then you walk over this *string* letter by letter (this is what your for-loop is doing). On every letter `var[i]` you try to read a property `userid`. I think no normal letter (calld `char`) hav a property called `userid`. So this result in an empty string.

I think you would like to get the array from the string `xmlhttp.responseText`. To do so you just let JSON parse this *string* and it gave you an *Object*.

`JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse